# AnythingSlider Fx Transition Flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anythingslider

On the first rotation of slides there is small flicker that occurs during the Fx transition. It seems to only occur on the first rotation of slides & goes away after the first repeat.

Demo Page:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12310886/Work/anythingslider/slide_left.html

Any ideas? I haven't been able to figure it out so far.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `mode` to `fade` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/5148/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('#slider').anythingSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        autoPlay: true,
        delay: 2000,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        buildStartStop: false,
        buildArrows: false
    }).anythingSliderFx({
        '.left .content-wrapper': ['left']
    }, {
        timeIn: 300,
        timeOut: 350,
        stopRepeat: true
    });
});
```